# Counting column with text against specified dates in Excel

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

I need to count the text in column B against the column A which consist of dates. For eg. If on 09/25/2019 the column consist of three names "Sukrut. Anand, Sam" but Anand is mentioned on thrice in rows against same date while Sam is twice and sukrut is once.

I exactly want to know the count of names occured on specific dates. Like for 09/25/2019 the names occured for how many times and so on.

I think this better should work with =Countifs or =Sumproduct

```
Date        Agent Name    Lead details       QA Status (Internal)    QA status (External)
5/9/2019    sukrut        abcd@jsfnak.com    Yes                     Yes
5/9/2019    sukrut        abcd@jsfnak.com    Yes                     No
5/9/2019    sam           abcd@jsfnak.com    No                      No
5/9/2019    sam           abcd@jsfnak.com    No                      No
5/9/2019    anand         abcd@jsfnak.com    No                      No
5/9/2019    sager         abcd@jsfnak.com    Yes                     Yes
5/10/2019   Sukrut        abcd@jsfnak.com    No                      No
5/11/2019   Sukrut        abcd@jsfnak.com    Yes                     No
```

This is what I tried using `=COUNTIF('6AEE97'!$A$3:$A$17,"5/9/2019") - COUNTIF('6AEE97'!$B$3:$B$17,"Sukrut")`

Comment: You're correct, Countifs sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I tried using =Countifs but not getting the exact value as required need to understand the "range_criteria"

Comment: You're going to need to provide sample data, the formula you tried, and the correct expected results.

Comment: No, edit your question to include the sample data.  Doesn't have to be real data, just need dummy data that's representative of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: can you please refer it now.

Comment: This is what i tried using =COUNTIF('6AEE97'!$A$3:$A$17,"5/9/2019") - COUNTIF('6AEE97'!$B$3:$B$17,"Sukrut")

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple pivot table is all you need.  Select your table and then Insert -> Pivot Table.  Setup your pivot table like so:

[image: Pivot Table Setup]

Then just remove grand totals (unless you want to keep them) and I also center-aligned the data to make it easier to review.  Here's the result:

[image: Pivot Table Result]

Comment: Agreed! That is also the possible way, but this is the raw data i have on Sheet 1 and  dashboard on Sheet 2. What im trying to do is automatically update the dashboard as i start putting data manually on raw data, so that gets reflected on my dashboard sheet.

Comment: @МяРэяғэст You can always right-click the pivot table and Refresh it, is that not sufficient?